# Change the value of the POS tag in NLTK Tree leaf

Tags: python, tree, nltk

I have an nltk.tree.Tree object.

```
t = Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [('I','tag')]), Tree('VP', [Tree('V', [('saw','tag')]), Tree('NP', [('him','tag')])])])
```

I want to traverse it with the function below, and change every leaf's POS tag (i.e. 'tag' in the above example).

```
def traverse(tree):
    try:
        tree.label()
    except AttributeError:
        tree[-1] = ('another_tag')
        print(tree)
    else:
        for child in tree:
            traverse(child)
```

Unfortunately, every POS-tag in the leaf cannot be changed because the tuple object including it is immutable.

How can I change the POS-tags in the example without affecting it's original tree structure?

I'm fairly new to this tree structure, please show some clear excerpts how to deal with nested structure.

Comment: create new Tree with the same structure, but when you encounter on POS you want, just change it.

Comment: @frankov Based on traverse function above, I've tried to produce a string like `(S (NP I) (VP (V saw) (NP him)))` , and changed it into Tree with `Tree.fromstring`. But It's not concise enough. Any hints or excerpts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An nltk tree is actually just a list.
With enumerate, you can loop through it and assign the node at position i a new value. Something like:

```
def traverse(tree):

    for index, subtree in enumerate(tree):
        if type(subtree) == nltk.tree.Tree:
            traverse(subtree)
        elif type(subtree) == tuple:
            newVal = (subtree[0], subtree[1].lower())
            subtree = newVal
            tree[index] = subtree
```

Because you're dealing with tuples (immutable), you cannot replace only the POStag, but have to create a new tuple.
The code above just makes the tag lowercase, but you can put in anything you like as second element of the newVal tuple.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what I want. Thank you so much.